# Jmeter: If the token is expired; then only I want to re-run Authorization API and update the token value

Tags: csv, jmeter, token

If the token is expired; then only I want to re-run Authorization API and update the token value.

For this purpose I am using two CSV file; one is for username and another one is for token.

Now when I run the authorization API; I check token is present or not for that user.

> Case 1. If not present then I am extracting the username, token, token
>   type, expiry date and issue date.
>
> Case 2. If present then I am checking token is expired or not, If
>   expired then Authorization API will run and updated the same in file.

First condition is working fine i.e API run successfully and the extracted date get entered into Token CSV file.

> I have problem with second condition; i.e. if against the respective user if
>   the expired date  is less than current date then I want to re-run the
>   Authorization and also update token, issue date and expiry date in the
>   token csv file. How can i achieve this.

I am trying to achive this If Controller, JSON Extractor and post-processor.
In if condition my expression is

```
${__groovy((vars.get("UserName").equalsIgnoreCase(vars.get("UserName_1")) && (("${__groovy(TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); Date date = new Date(); date.format("EE'\,' dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'");,)}".compareTo(vars.get("ExpiresDate")) < 0)) || vars.get("ExpiresDate").equalsIgnoreCase("<EOF>"))
,)}
```

I am attaching the JMX file in this given link
[https://filebin.net/gj0q3pyiaqlogt0w]

Please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot have 2 [__groovy() functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) in the If Controller's "Condition" area as it will not be recognized as a valid condition
2. [Date.format()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#format(java.lang.String)) function returns a [String](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html) so your compareTo() function is actually being called on [String object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-). I believe you should be rather comparing 2 dates so you need to amend this part of the condition to:]

   ```
   (new Date().compareTo(Date.parse("EE',' dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'", vars.get("ExpiresDate"))) < 0
   ```
3. In general you can run a request conditionally as simple as putting the relevant [Module Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) as a child of the If Controller, check out [Easily Write a GOTO Statement in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/easily-write-a-goto-statement-in-jmeter) article for more details.
4. The link to your test is broken, if you need further assistance consider providing Test Plan and all associated data (i.e. CSV files, possible variable values, etc.)

Comment: here is the updated link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/li6rf712u04l4me/Dummy.zip?dl=0

Comment: I modified  if condition to ${__groovy((!vars.get("UserName_1").equals(vars.get("UserName"))) || (new Date().compareTo(Date.parse("EE dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"\, vars.get("ExpiresDate"))) > 0)
This is working fine. However I want to update token, issue date and expiry date in the token csv file if the username exist in the token file. How can I achieve this?
,)}